# Why is $C^\infty(M)$-module homomorphism $P\mapsto\Gamma(P)$ surjective?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, modules

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}
\require{cancel}$
Jet Nestruev's "Smooth Manifolds and Observables" contains following exercise:

> **Exercise.** Show that $P$ is geometric if and only if the two modules $P$ and $\Gamma(P)$ are isomorphic.

It is clear that there is an injective map from $P$ to $\Gamma(P)$ iff $P$ is geometric. However, I do not see why this map needs to be surjective. I doubt that it holds, cause $\Gamma(P)$ is "sort of bidual" of $P.$

---

**Notions and the question.**

Let $P$ be a $C^\infty(M)$-module. We define following objects. For any $x\in M$
$$\mu_x:=\lbrace f\in C^\infty(M): f(x)=0\rbrace \hspace{5pt}\text{and}\hspace{5pt}P_x:=P/\mu_xP \hspace{5pt}\text{with}\hspace{5pt}\pi_x:P\to P_x.$$
Next we define
$$|P|:=\bigcup_{x\in M}P_x\hspace{5pt}\text{with}\hspace{5pt}\pi_P:|P|\to M\hspace{5pt}\text{and}\hspace{5pt}\Gamma(P):=\overbrace{\cancel{\lbrace s:M\to|P|: \pi_P\circ s=\Id_M\rbrace}}^{\color{red}{\text{MY MISREAD! IT IS DEFINED AS }\phi(P)}}.$$

We will say that $P$ is **geometric** if 
$$\bigcap_{x\in M}\mu_xP=0.$$

For convenience consider natural $C^\infty(M)$-module homomorphism $\phi:P\to\Gamma(P)$ 
$$\phi(p)(x):=\pi_x(p)$$

> **Question.** Why is $\phi$ surjective? Is geometricity needed for $\phi$ to be surjective?

---

**Some note after Wille Liou's comment.**

It is suspicious that they made no constraints on sections (elements of $\Gamma(P))$. If we consider $P=C^\infty(M)$, then $\Gamma(P)$ contains all functions from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: What topology is put on $|P|$?

Comment: @WilleLiou Section 11.12 is devoted to topology in $|P|.$ Shortly, it is the Zariski topology of the symmetric algebra $S(P^\vee)$ viewed as functions on $|P|.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exercise is fine. I misread the definition of $\Gamma(P).$ Jet Nestruev defines $\Gamma(P)$ as an image $\phi(P).$ Hence surjectivity follows obviously from the definition of $\Gamma(P)$.

Comment: You can accept this answer to take your question off the unanswered list.